# UIImagePickerController with Tab Bar Controller

Tags: objective-c, iphone, camera

I need to create a tab bar app with acess the camera in the third section of tab bar, but a try with `[self.view insertSubview:overlay.view atIndex:1];` and doesn't work. They don't load the camera. How i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the UITabBarDelegate didSelectItem method and push the Image Picker Controller when the third tab is selected.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html